# How to bind a UserControl's property to a property?

Tags: wpf, xaml

I'd like to set a property of a re-defined UserControl (for example its background color) to a property of the class. For example.
If I define the background of a Button to a property (`<Button x:Name="myButton" Background="{Binding ColorName}"/>`), it works fine. However, if I do the same for a re-defined UserControl (`<local:MyUserControl Background="{Binding Path=ColorName}"/>`), it does not.

What's funny though, is that, if I do `<local:MyUserControl Background="{Binding Background, ElementName=myButton}"/>`, it works perfectly fine.

Could I have some help on that? I must be missing something.

Thanks!

**EDIT**

Here is all the code. The setting of the background color worked fine. What solved this was to set properly the `MainWindow.DataContext` and to remove the `DataContext = this` in `MyUserControl.xaml.cs`. Setting `Color` as a `DependencyProperty` is also useful to be able to change the Color setting in a later execution of the code.
Nonetheless, while removing `DataContext=this` in `MyUserControl.xaml.cs`, 
the `{Binding TextContent}` does not work and needs to be replaced by `{Binding TextContent, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=c:MyUserControl}}`.

#### MainWindow.xaml

```xml
<Window x:Class="BindingBug.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:c="clr-namespace:BindingBug"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525"
        DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}">

    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="1*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="1*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="1*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Button Background="{Binding Path=Color}"
                Width="250" 
                Height="30"
                Content="I am bound to be RED!"
                Grid.Row="0"
                x:Name="myButton"/>
        <c:MyUserControl Background="{Binding Background, ElementName=myButton}"
                Width="250" 
                Height="30"
                Content="I am bound to be RED!"
                Grid.Row="1"/>
        <c:MyUserControl Background="{Binding Path=Color}"
                Width="250" 
                Height="30"
                Content="I am bound to be RED!"
                Grid.Row="2"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

#### MainWindow.xaml.cs

```cs
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Media;

namespace BindingBug
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            Color = Brushes.Red;
        }

        public static readonly DependencyProperty ColorProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Color", typeof(Brush), typeof(MainWindow));

        public Brush Color
        {
            get
            {
                return (Brush)GetValue(ColorProperty);
            }
            set
            {
                SetValue(ColorProperty, value);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

#### MyUserControl.xaml

```xml
<UserControl x:Class="BindingBug.MyUserControl"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
             xmlns:c="clr-namespace:BindingBug"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="1*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="2*" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" 
                   FontSize="13"
                   Text="{Binding TextContent, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=c:MyUserControl}}"
                   VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

#### MyUserControl.xaml.cs

```cs
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;

namespace BindingBug
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for NumberDataHolder.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MyUserControl : UserControl
    {
        public MyUserControl()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public static readonly DependencyProperty TextContentProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("TextContent", typeof(string), typeof(MyUserControl));

        public string TextContent
        {
            get
            {
                return (string)GetValue(TextContentProperty);
            }
            set
            {
                SetValue(TextContentProperty, value);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**EDIT 2**

I tried to acheive the same results without having to declare the whole `Text="{Binding TextContent, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=c:MyUserControl}}"` inside `TextBlock`. So, following @KeithStein advice, I placed `DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"` inside `MyUserControl` and only kept `Text="{Binding TextContent}"`inside `TextBlock`. That, however cancels the effect of setting `Background="{Binding Path=Color}"` in `MainWindow.xaml`. Any idea why? Is there another possibility to set `Background="{Binding Path=Color}"` in `MainWindow.xaml` and to only keep`Text="{Binding TextContent}"`inside `TextBlock`?

#### MainWindow.xaml

```xml
<Window x:Class="BindingBug.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:c="clr-namespace:BindingBug"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525"
        DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}">

    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="1*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="1*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="1*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Button Background="{Binding Path=Color}"
                Width="250" 
                Height="30"
                Content="I am bound to be RED!"
                Grid.Row="0"
                x:Name="myButton"/>
        <c:MyUserControl Background="{Binding Background, ElementName=myButton}"
                Width="250" 
                Height="30"
                Content="I am bound to be RED!"
                Grid.Row="1"/>
        <c:MyUserControl Background="{Binding Path=Color}"
                Width="250" 
                Height="30"
                Content="I am bound to be RED!"
                Grid.Row="2"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

#### MainWindow.xaml.cs

```cs
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Media;

namespace BindingBug
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            Color = Brushes.Red;
        }

        public static readonly DependencyProperty ColorProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Color", typeof(Brush), typeof(MainWindow));

        public Brush Color
        {
            get
            {
                return (Brush)GetValue(ColorProperty);
            }
            set
            {
                SetValue(ColorProperty, value);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

#### MyUserControl.xaml

```xml
<UserControl x:Class="BindingBug.MyUserControl"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
             xmlns:c="clr-namespace:BindingBug"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300"
        DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="1*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="2*" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" 
                   FontSize="13"
                   Text="{Binding TextContent}"
                   VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

#### MyUserControl.xaml.cs

```cs
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;

namespace BindingBug
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for NumberDataHolder.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MyUserControl : UserControl
    {
        public MyUserControl()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public static readonly DependencyProperty TextContentProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("TextContent", typeof(string), typeof(MyUserControl));

        public string TextContent
        {
            get
            {
                return (string)GetValue(TextContentProperty);
            }
            set
            {
                SetValue(TextContentProperty, value);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: ["Attribute"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/attributes/) means something specific in .NET. It doesn't look like that's what you're talking about. Do you mean a [property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/properties)?

Comment: @KeithStein, yes you are right. I mis-used the word attribute. I changed that

Comment: Have you set `DataContext` anywhere? You should really include your code in your question.

Comment: @KeithStein, I added all the code in the publication. Thanks for your help

Comment: One thing that seems odd is that `ColorName` is a `string` not a `Brush`. I'm not sure that would work at all unless there's some implicit conversion I don't know about. Try replacing `ColorName` with a `Brush`-type property, or use an `IValueConverter`, and see if that helps.

Comment: @KeithStein thanks for your answer. I tried to put ```Color``` as a ```Brush``` instead of a ```string``` but that did not work. I also figured out how to implement that without using ```MyDataSource.cs``` as I used to so I cleant the code a little bit. 
I am not sure I understand what you propose with the ```IValueConverter```. Could you be more specific please?
Thanks again

Comment: What I meant is that if you couldn't use a `Brush` type property, you could implement an `IValueConverter` to convert from `String` to `Brush`. A couple problems with your new code, though:

Comment: First, since you removed `MyDataSource`, you no longer set `MainWindow.DataContext` anywhere. Add `DataContext={Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}` to the opening tag of `MainWindow` so it refers to itself as the data source.

Comment: Second, the bindings on `MainWindow` are first called during `InitializeComponent`, but you don't set `ColorName` until after that call. Since `ColorName` is not a dependency property, the binding will be called before it is given its value and then never updated again. Either set `ColorName` before calling `InitializeComponent`, or make `ColorName` a dependency property (do the later if you intend to change the value after initialization).

Comment: Thanks for your help @KeithStein. Setting ```MainWindow.DataContext``` did the trick. Can you also explain to me why I also needed to remove the ```DataContaxt=this;``` from the ```MyUserControl.xaml.cs``` please?
Also, do you understand why it worked with ```Background="{Binding Background, ElementName=myButton}"```?

Comment: I still have a tiny issue with the ```DependencyProperty```. Removing ```DataContext=this``` from ```MyUserControl.xaml.cs``` forces me to write ```{Binding TextContent, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=c:MyUserControl}}```. is there a way to have the 2 ```DataContext```s in parallel?

Comment: `DataContext` serves as the default source for bindings. `ElementName` overrides that source and instead uses the element which bears the given name. That's why `ElementName` worked. As for the binding inside inside the `UserControl`, adding `DataContext={Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}` to the opening tag should fix it just like with `MainWindow`. As for `DataContaxt=this`, it appeared after `InitializeComponent`, so when the bindings first fired it wasn't set yet.

Comment: Ok, I understand ! However, setting ```DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"``` in the ```UserControl``` cancels the ```Background="{Binding Color}"``` set in ```MainWindow.xaml```

Comment: Hm, you'll have to show the code. I don't know why that would happen.

Comment: @KeithStein, I added a second edit to the code with he explanation of the changes and what doesn't work.

Comment: Ah, I see my mistake. Don't set `DataContext` in the opening tag of `MyUserControl`. Instead, you'll set it on the root `Grid` inside the control. Add this to the opening `Grid` tag: `DataContext={Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=c:MyUserControl}}`

Comment: That did the trick ! Thanks a lot for your help @KeithStein!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This answer developed gradually through back and forth comments with OP. To summarize:

- Use a `Brush`-type dependency property for your color. `Brush` because that is the type of the `Background` property that you want to bind to, and a dependency property so that updates of the property trigger any bindings to refresh.
- When binding inside a `Window` or `UserControl`, you need to set [`DataContext`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.frameworkelement.datacontext), which is essentially the default sourced used by bindings.

  - For a `Window`, add `DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"` to the opening tag. This sets the default source for all controls contained within to the `Window` itself.
  - For a `UserControl`, add the following to the outer-most panel of said control: `DataContext={Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}}` (`UserControl` can be replaced with the name of your particular control, i.e. `c:MyUserControl`). This tells everything inside that root panel to use the `UserControl` as the default source. You can't use `RelativeSource Self` in this case, because then instances of the `MyUserControl` will bind to themselves when placed inside `Window`s, instead of inheriting the `Window`'s `DataContext`.